# WYSIWYG magento issue in admin

Tags: magento, wysiwyg, rich-text-editor

I have a problem with one magento installation version 1.7.0.2

when I try to upload an image through the WYSIWYG editor in the cms pages for example when I click on browse server I get this error:

```
error: error in [unknown object].fireEvent():    
event name: open_browser_callback    
error message: Dialog is not defined
```

SO far I haven't found the same error so if anyone can help out I'd be very grateful.

Also in product WYSIWYG editor it doesn't load and says

Window is not defined.

I guess the error is the same.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem on 1.6. Fixed it by overwriting the complete js folder

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on 1.7.0

I go to the Magento "old versions" repository and downloaded the whole CMS

Then I replaced the whole existing js folder in that the fresh installation...it works :)